# Integrating SharePoint 2013 with SSRS report Data or Extracting Data from SSRS into SharePoint using a TimerJob

Tags: c#, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-timer-job

I have a requirement to get data out of an SQL Server Reporting Services based system straight into a SharePoint list from where that data will then be processed.

At present, users export the data into an Excel spreadsheet and then start modifying columns on that spreadsheet and exchange it among various stakeholders every two hours.

My intention is to bypass the export to Excel portion of the current process and instead create a timer job (created using .NET, C# and SSOM) that gets the data directly out of SSRS into my SharePoint List.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with SSRS, I suppose you know ETL also, so you could import the updated excel spreadsheet(maybe from a fixed path, so you just need save the files there) to a SQL Server table. Then create external content type from the table and display data in SharePoint by creating external list.

[One thread for your reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/bcs-using-sql-server-in-sharepoint-2013/)